# "android:windowLightStatusBar" not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I seriously do not how this is not working. Even though I do have an API way beyond 23 the status bar text color remains white even when `windowLighStatusBar` is set to `true`. Here is my application theme:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/offWhite</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/offWhite</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/monaYellow</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/bluePowder</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/offWhite</item>

    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Can you check if you've set any theming code programatically in your activity? Also verify once that you haven't set any other theme for your activity in manifest.

Comment: I have tested your code on android 10 google pixel emulator it is working, by changing value of windowLightStatusBar attribute, status_bar _text_color  changing, send your activity code also!

Answer (score 3):

Because you are setting;

```
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

I think you also want to set;

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

---

Details of `windowLightNavigationBar` from the docs:

> "For this to take effect, the window must be drawing the system bar
>   backgrounds with windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds and the status bar
>   must not have been requested to be translucent with
>   windowTranslucentStatus."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#windowLightStatusBar

Answer (score 1):

You can set it programmatically for API>=23 like this:

```
window!!.decorView.systemUiVisibility=View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
```

Call this before setting contentView() in Activity

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant statusBarColor only to change its colors

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/yourcolor</item>
```

Comment: No.

ColorPrimaryDark already takes care of that for me. But I want grey text color on my status bar which I cant seem to get.